# How to specify SSL/TLS client extensions?

Tags: python, python-3.x, ssl, openssl, handshake

To my understanding a client can attach a list of desired tls extensions during the [client handshake](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5246#section-7.4.1.2) message. So how do I this in python? I didn't find anything related in the [docu](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/ssl.html#ssl.SSLContext). I want to be able to pick any of the [official ones](http://www.iana.org/assignments/tls-extensiontype-values/tls-extensiontype-values.xhtml) but being able to use [session resumption](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5077) would be a great start.

Glad for any hints :o)

Comment: You found a solution to this?

Answer (score 1):

The standard library's [`ssl` module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ssl.html) does not expose options for
controlling which TLS extensions are used.

PyOpenSSL does provide the [`OpenSSL.SSL.OP_NO_TICKET` constant](https://pyopenssl.readthedocs.org/en/stable/api/ssl.html#OpenSSL.SSL.OP_NO_TICKET) which
can be used [`Context.set_options`](https://pyopenssl.readthedocs.org/en/stable/api/ssl.html#OpenSSL.SSL.OP_NO_TICKET) to *disable* the session resumption extension.  (Presumably this means that it is enabled by default).